# Connect to Navision with Petapoco or Dapper using ODBC

Tags: orm, dapper, petapoco, navision

I'm trying to connecto to Navision 2.60 using ODBC. I have a static class to manage the odbc connection.

I want to use a ORM for mapping entities like Petapoco or Dapper, does anyone have an example of doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var db = new Database("DSN=MYDSN", "System.Data.Odbc"); db.OpenSharedConnection();
```

Comment: This will not work. PetaPoco currently does not support ODBC. I tried lot of ways to force PetaPoco to use ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

As for dapper, there are many many many examples @ Github.
[Dapper Tests & Examples](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Tests/Tests.cs)

And here's some PetaPoco stuff. [Peta Poco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/)

Haven't you found anything on google?

Comment: var db = new Database("DSN=MYDSN", "System.Data.Odbc");
            db.OpenSharedConnection();